# Is it possible to import a class from Materialize into an SCSS file?

Tags: css, sass, django-templates

I'm writing some HTML within a `div` element with class `lucy-terms`. Within that element, I'd like all `p` elements to automatically have Materialize's class [`flow-text`](http://materializecss.com/typography.html) added to them.

Here is a snippet of the HTML (actually a Django template using [`django-sass-processor`](https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor):

```
{% load sass_tags %}

<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Materialize.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link href="{% sass_src 'stylesheets/terms_of_service.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container lucy-terms">
    <h4 class="center-align">Terms of Use</h4>
    <p class="flow-text">PLEASE NOTE THAT YOUR USE OF AND ACCESS TO OUR SERVICES (DEFINED BELOW) ARE SUBJECT TO THE FOLLOWING TERMS. IF YOU DO NOT AGREE TO ALL OF THE FOLLOWING, YOU MAY NOT USE OR ACCESS THE SERVICES IN ANY MANNER.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is `stylesheets/terms_of_service.scss`:

```
.lucy-terms p {
  // @extend .flow-text;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Note that `@extend .flow-text;` is commented out. If I comment it in, I get the following error:

> Error: ".lucy-terms p" failed to @extend ".flow-text".
>          The selector ".flow-text" was not found.
>
> Use "@extend .flow-text !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
>
> on line 2 of lucy_web/static/stylesheets/terms_of_service.scss

Basically, within `terms_of_service.scss`, the `flow-text` class is not defined; it is defined in the Materialize source code. So I would have to add something like (in 'Python pseudocode')

```
from materialize import flow-text
```

Is it possible to import classes from external 'libraries' in SCSS?

**Update**

Incidentally, here is something I tried that didn't work. I thought that the `@extend` might work if the Materialize source code and my own CSS were both included into a single file. I tried to achieve this using [`django-compressor`](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) like so:

```
{% load static %}
{% load sass_tags %}
{% load compress %}

<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Materialize.css -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">-->
    {% compress css %}
    <link href="{% static 'stylesheets/vendor/materialize.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{% sass_src 'stylesheets/terms_of_service.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    {% endcompress %}
  </head>
```

where I refer to a version of Materialize in the local static files instead of one from a CDN (because Django Compressor chokes on the latter). Unfortunately, however, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I that to do this, I needed to use the source version (in SCSS) of Materialize, not the standard version (in CSS). So, instead of `stylesheets/vendor/materialize.css`, I now have a `stylesheets/vendor/materialize.scss` (together with the accompanying `components` directory). Then in my own SCSS, I can do

```
@import 'vendor/materialize'

.lucy-terms p {
  @extend .flow-text;
}
```

and it works as expected.